# magento unable to send email

Tags: php, magento, email

Suddenly I am having this very weird problem.
When I try to email an invoice, i get this error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppmbp6v02gwsrpg/Screenshot%202014-01-06%2009.01.55.png

My email communication is turned on. I know when I put email communication off, I get errors like this 'This Letter cannot be send', which is normal because I turned them off.

It's very strange, I didn't make any modifications to the system and suddenly some emails wont send automatically. (or I did change something but I don't remember what?)

Can somebody help me with this problem?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Set the hostname correctly and restart sendmail.

Comment: how are you able to restart sendmail?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with sending email via php. You should check PHP error log or apache error log. Also you can try to install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html